# How to add labels or metadata to GCE Instance from within the instance itself?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, metadata, gcloud

I need a way to list instances and startup scripts executing status (`installing`, `preparing`, `done`, ...).

`labels` and `metadata` are returned via `instances.list` result while console output require additional requests `instance.describe` for each instance.

However, when I use `gcloud` from within the instance itself, it throw error

```bash
startup-script: WARNING: Could not open the configuration file: [/root/.config/gcloud/configurations/config_default].
startup-script: ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.add-labels) You do not currently have an active account selected.
```

Comment: One challenge in using `gcloud` on a Compute Engine VM is that you need to authenticate it for use. You should use a Service Account but, to do so (using `gcloud`), you need to [`gcloud auth activate-service-account`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/activate-service-account) which requires having a Service Account key accessible to the command and this is challenging.

Comment: Ideally you'd want to leverage the Metadata service to acquire e.g. an auth token that you can use to auth requests (but `gcloud` doesn't facilitate that). It is likely better to write a script in your preferred language to call the Compute Engine library and effect these changes that way. Using a Google-provided library, [Application Default Credentails (ADC)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication#adc) can be used as this mechanism will acquire the VM's Service Account credentials automatically for you.

Comment: FYI: do not run the CLI tools as the root user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To report the status of startup scripts, consider using [guest attributes](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/manage-guest-attributes) instead:

> Guest attributes are a specific type of custom metadata that your applications can write to while running on your virtual machine (VM) instance. Any application or user on your VM instance can both read and write data to these guest attribute metadata values.

You can think of guest attributes as the complement to metadata: While metadata lets you pass data *to* the guest, guest attributes are a way to let the guest pass data (such as [status information](https://jpassing.com/2020/04/17/how-do-i-know-when-my-vm-is-ready-to-connect/)) back.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to pass `access_token` directly from my app to the `startup-script` and use `curl` to invoke `googleapis` directly.